# android throw InvocationTargetException,How to modify the error

Tags: android

```
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)this.getSystemService(this.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

  try {
   clearMethod = am.getClass()
     .getMethod("clearApplicationUserData", String.class,
       IPackageDataObserver.class);
  } catch (Exception e) {
   Log.e("Error", "Android Error",e);
   clearMethod = null;
  } 

  if(clearMethod!=null){
   try {
    clearMethod.invoke(am,"com.android.browser",new ClearUserDataObserver());
   } catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("Error", "Android Exception",e);
   } 
  }



Exception 

05-26 08:34:13.056: ERROR/Error(739): java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
05-26 08:34:13.056: ERROR/Error(739):     at android.app.ActivityManager.clearApplicationUserData(ActivityManager.java:475)
05-26 08:34:13.056: ERROR/Error(739):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-26 08:34:13.056: ERROR/Error(739):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-26 08:34:13.056: ERROR/Error(739):     at com.iwidsets.clear.manager.AndClear.onCreate(AndClear.java:34)
05-26 08:34:13.056: ERROR/Error(739):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1123)
05-26 08:34:13.056: ERROR/Error(739):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2364)
05-26 08:34:13.056: ERROR/Error(739):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)
05-26 08:34:13.056: ERROR/Error(739):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:116)
05-26 08:34:13.056: ERROR/Error(739):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
05-26 08:34:13.056: ERROR/Error(739):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-26 08:34:13.056: ERROR/Error(739):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-26 08:34:13.056: ERROR/Error(739):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4203)
05-26 08:34:13.056: ERROR/Error(739):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-26 08:34:13.056: ERROR/Error(739):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-26 08:34:13.056: ERROR/Error(739):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
05-26 08:34:13.056: ERROR/Error(739):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:549)
05-26 08:34:13.056: ERROR/Error(739):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-26 08:34:13.056: ERROR/Error(739): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: 739 does not have permission:android.permission.CLEAR_APP_USER_DATA to clear datafor process:com.android.browser
05-26 08:34:13.056: ERROR/Error(739):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1218)
05-26 08:34:13.056: ERROR/Error(739):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1206)
05-26 08:34:13.056: ERROR/Error(739):     at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.clearApplicationUserData(ActivityManagerNative.java:2016)
05-26 08:34:13.056: ERROR/Error(739):     ... 17 more
```

---

This is my androidManifest.xml file

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.iwidsets.clear.manager"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".AndClear"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CLEAR_APP_USER_DATA"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CLEAR_APP_CACHE"></uses-permission>
</manifest>
```

Comment: What do you want to do there?

Answer (score 1):

You can't modify the error.

You are missing a permission, check out this line in your logcat output:

```
.SecurityException: 739 does not have permission:android.permission.CLEAR_APP_USER_DATA to clear datafor process:com.android.browser
```

Answer (score 0):

As the java API states:

> InvocationTargetException is a checked
>   exception that wraps an exception
>   thrown by an invoked method or
>   constructor.

It seems that somewhere in your method clearApplicationUserData there is an Exception

Edit: an as pentium10 pointed out there is the permission missing for your clearApplicationUserData method.

Comment: public boolean clearApplicationUserData(String packageName, IPackageDataObserver observer) {
        try {
            return ActivityManagerNative.getDefault().clearApplicationUserData(packageName, 
                    observer);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

```
    public boolean clearApplicationUserData(String packageName, IPackageDataObserver observer) {
    try {
        return ActivityManagerNative.getDefault().clearApplicationUserData(packageName, 
                observer);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```